# How to debug behaviour in IE6/7 which works completely error-free in other browsers

Tags: testing, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Question is really simple, I am unable to find out what is wrong with this page:

http://www.ezotour.sk/page/poznavacie-zajazdy-taliansko-sicilia.html

I have tried firebug no errors, I have tried chrome with no errors, I have tried IE9 with no errors. Using IETester it will return errors in code but I am not able to find out what it is.

I don't want you to debug my page for me, I need some advice what you use for IE6/7 debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IETester is buggy, don't trust it.

The best way to test across multiple browsers is to create different virtual machine configurations using VMWare.

See: http://civicactions.com/blog/2009/may/24/building_ultimate_cross_browser_testing_system

Answer (score 0):

IE6 is buggy, but not for a long time!

http://ie6countdown.com/

Comment: I know that, however there are clients who still need ie6/7 functionality. sorry, but most useless answer i got in long time.

Comment: I guess you didn't get my humor. Manual tuning of new website features to work fine in IE6 is about 1/5th of my everyday work. So I could not find anything more serious to answer on your simple and naive question about "where to get software that would fix it all for you".

Comment: I am trying to find console, something like Firebug for IE so I can see why all browsers work but IE is unhappy. Or do you know instantly what is the error message on that page? Please share